# Why are Lifecycle Events disabled in Visual Studio debugging on WP10 device?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, windows-10-mobile

I have a C#/XAML app that I am debugging on my Windows 10 Phone using Visual Studio 2015. I can set breakpoints and stop at them, and do just about any other typical debugging action. But the Lifecycle Events are all disabled in the Lifecycle Events menu/button in the VS Debug Location toolbar..

The only thing interesting is that I'm using someone else's library for audio recording and I think that the library only comes with an ARM version, not an "Any CPU" version.

I have no idea what setting might be wrong that won't let me test tombstoning in my app. Any ideas how to get those Lifecycle Event options enabled?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a Windows 8.0 app, not 8.1 and not UWP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are disabled because those menu items are only available for Windows Store apps, not for WIndows 8/8.1 apps. Use the "Tombstone on deactivation" checkbox in the app settings to make it do tombstoning. Then debug the app and go the Start screen while the app is running; the app will deactivate as expected.